# joomla and jquery conflict

Tags: joomla2.5, conflict, jquery

I had been through most of the conflict-resolving codes online [jquery.noConflict()] etc. And had tried  using joomla plugin : jquery easy to try and do resolve it. None of it works for me. Here is the problem:

The top menu of the joomla website uses jquery to display the content, while the sidebar is just joomla's positioning of the menu elements.

**With jquery.noConflict():**
The top menu would work. The sidebar menu will not be clickable. [Only right-click and open in new tab then it will display the content]

**If I had jQuery codes removed all together:**
The top menu will, of course, fail to work. The sidebar menu will then be clickable.

So it is either top menu or the sidebar that would work, exclusively. Any suggestion?

My jQuery codes are as follows, in case I did something wrong. >< - currently using jquery easy plugin to :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[ 
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
        jQuery('#link1').click(function(e){    
            jQuery('#exposeMask, #csmf1').fadeIn('slow');
        });
        jQuery('#link2').click(function(e){    
            jQuery('#exposeMask, #csmf2').fadeIn('slow');
        });
        jQuery('#link3').click(function(e){    
            jQuery('#exposeMask, #csmf3').fadeIn('slow');
        });
        jQuery('#link4').click(function(e){    
            jQuery('#exposeMask, #csmf4').fadeIn('slow');
        });

        jQuery('#closebtn1').click(function(e){    
            jQuery('#exposeMask, #csmf1').fadeOut('slow');
        });
        jQuery('#closebtn2').click(function(e){    
            jQuery('#exposeMask, #csmf2').fadeOut('slow');
        });
        jQuery('#closebtn3').click(function(e){    
            jQuery('#exposeMask, #csmf3').fadeOut('slow');
        });
        jQuery('#closebtn4').click(function(e){    
            jQuery('#exposeMask, #csmf4').fadeOut('slow');
        });
        checkTab(); 
    });//]]> 
        function switchContent(obj) { 
            obj = (!obj) ? 'tab1' : obj; 

            var contentDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); 
            for (i=0; i<contentDivs.length; i++) { 
                if (contentDivs[i].id && contentDivs[i].id.indexOf('tab') !== -1) { 
                    contentDivs[i].className = 'hide';          
                } 
            } 
            document.getElementById(obj).className = ''; 
            jQuery(".current").removeClass("active");
            jQuery(".current").removeClass("current");
        } 
        function checkTab() { 
            jQuery('a').each(function() { 
                jQuery(this).click(function() { 
                    tab = jQuery(this).attr('href').split('#'); 
                    switchContent(tab[1]); 
                    jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
                    jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('current');
                    return false;
                }); 
            }); 
        } 
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you ensured that you are only importing 1 jquery file?

Comment: Can you check the console in your browser (F12 for most browsers) and see if it logs any Javascript errors there?

Comment: @Lodder yup, only 1 jquery file.

Comment: @Bakual yup, no javascript error. Even clicking the menu doesn't  register a click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `checkTab()` function.
It is applied to each link and may interfere with other links in the sidebar. Maybe make this function less generic so it only applies to links in your top menu.

Comment: Yes, i had changed from "return false" to "return true" lol, somehow it worked. Thanks!